# Mathjax 2.3 beta

Tags: support, status-completed, mathjax

**UPDATE:  Mathjax 2.3 is now live**

We have deployed the latest Mathjax 2.3 beta on Math.SE. As with any beta release please post an answer to this question if you find any issues. We will be monitoring this thread closely along with the authors of Mathjax to ensure this release goes smoothly.

For a list of features included in this release check [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues?milestone=1&state=closed)

Comment: Is it because of this implementation that math takes much longer time to be compiled? If yes, I would really prefer the previous version.

Comment: Did the changes get pushed out within past hour? On my firefox, Math.SE suddenly switch to use image fonts to render the equations and its looks pretty ugly.

Comment: @achillehui I have exactly the same phenomenon.

Comment: I also notice the same thing as O.L that it takes much much longer time to render the equations.

Comment: I have observed the performance issues as well as the image rendering in Firefox.  I have pulled testing of this beta for now until we can get a resolution.

Comment: Thank you for the update, Geoff. Also for pulling out the beta testing until this horrible issue can be resolved! As always, your efforts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: @GeoffDalgas The MathJax team reports to have fixed the issue with delays and image rendering in Firefox.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I'm still waiting on a final confirmation via email before deploying this beta again.

Comment: We have confirmation - Mathjax 2.3 beta has been enabled again on math.se

Comment: It feel slightly slower than 2.2. However, if I haven't told  2.3 has rolled out, I won't be able to detect the difference.

Comment: @achillehui that's probably because your browser hasn't cached all MathJax components yet. MathJax is very modular and will only load the components needed for the actual content (e.g. minimal set of webfonts, not all TeX extensions). If you visit http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference this will load almost all MathJax components. If you experience speed issues related to typesetting after that, please let us know.

Comment: @Peter: Is it possible to change the default font from the end-user side, or within the code (e.g. `\selectfont`-like functionality)? [Also, it's always fun to see you 'round here! :-)]

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes and no. There's no such command (and it wouldn't be trivial to implement it but font mixing is in our backlog). For development purposes, MathJax has a submenu for global font selection which is not active by default. It's not very stable because it didn't make sense in production environments until now. We could fix the menu but it would still be up to page authors (i.e. StackExchange) to offer that option.

Comment: @Peter: I see. I think. Thanks for the information, and the work you put into this project! (and other projects as well, by the way!)

Comment: I’ve not noticed that it’s any slower when I open a new page, but it does seems to take less MathJax in an answer to reach the point at which the typesetting of the preview becomes painfully slow — slow enough so that I break the answer into sections, type the sections in answer windows for several different questions, and then combine them.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott did anything else change in your setup (browser updates etc)? Also, did you see this consistently at a certain complexity or was it particular content? Finally, what browser & OS are you experiencing this? Not sure if a separate thread is appropriate to collect other people's feedback on this.

Comment: @Peter: No changes. I’ve been using Firefox $24.0$ on Windows $7$ Home Premium. When I have that much content, it usually includes `\begin{align*}\end{align*}` blocks or arrays, sometimes quite long.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks. That's very odd. If you have a sample, could you try it at http://beta.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-dynamic-2.html ? (So that we see if it's due to math.SE's editing environment.)

Comment: @Peter: The rendering engine there works very differently, which makes it very hard to compare. If I drop a whole answer into at once, it pauses, then displays the whole thing at once. If I do the same thing in an answer window, text displays immediately, and I can see the blur clearing as the MathJax renders. When I’m typing there, there’s a perceptible delay between keystroke and appearance of letter; when I type into an answer window the letters appear immediately, but when I stop typing it may take several seconds for the MathJax to render.

Answer (score 6):

I see some formulae in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/546657/19661) completely messed up when viewed with Internet Explorer 11 (with Chrome it is OK):

[image]

Comment: Apparently, it only happens if I paste the URL in the address bar, but not when I click the link.

Comment: Works fine on Firefox 25.0, Arch Linux 64bit (kernel version 3.11.6-1). Both clicking and opening as a new tab and pasting the address.

Comment: Hi @VladimirReshetnikov I cannot reproduce this on a clean VM with IE11. Does it disappear on refreshing the page? This looks like a typical webfont detection error which can occur if the webfonts aren't downloaded in time. Since this is a connection issue, it usually disappears on a refresh. Can you confirm that?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger It consistently reproduces on my side (only if I paste the URL into the address bar manually). Closing and reopening the browser, refreshing the page, resizing the window do not help. Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.16384, Windows 8.1 Enterprise x64.

Comment: Thanks, @VladimirReshetnikov ! That's pretty strange. I will try again to reproduce it.

Comment: It reproduces on my colleague's machine as well.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov, do you have the MathJax fonts installed locally?  As a temporary fix, you might try switching to SVG output, since that will avoid font download issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this, neither on a VM nor on browserstack.com. Perhaps resetting IE as much as you can might help.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Because it only happens if I manually paste the URL into the address bar, and nobody else complaining about it, I would say - do not worry about this issue. Thanks for trying to reproduce!

Comment: I also can't reproduce this, Windows 7 SP1, IE 11.0.9600.16428. I suggest following @DavideCervone's advice. When I've had issues with MathJax rendering in the past, the problem was that I had downloaded local copies of the MathJax fonts and they were prioritized on page load.